# Cant list files in a shared drive folder using the google drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Google drive API cant detect files I havent opened at least once in a shared drive folder (via link). I'm trying to list files in a drive folder that was shared to me via link, but when I tried to do that my code kept telling me there is nothing in the folder. I tried opening one of the files and noticed that now this specific files shows up. I think that the drive api only sees files as "shared with me" once I opened them at least once.

The only working solution I found was copying the entire shared folder into my own drive storage, though I'm sure its obvious that thats not an elegant solution. I think that a possible solution is asking the owner to add me as one of the viewers via mail and not a sharing link, but I'm afraid thats not possible..

Heres the code I tried using:

```py
from Google import Create_Service
import pandas as pd
folder_id='----shared folder id----'
query=f"parents in '{folder_id}' and trashed=false"
result=service.files().list(
    q=query,
    includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
    supportsAllDrives=True
).execute()
files=result.get('files')
nextPageToken=result.get('nextPageToken')
while nextPageToken:
    result=service.files().list(q=query,includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,supportsAllDrives=True,pageToken=nextPageToken).execute()
    files.extend(result.get('files'))
    nextPageToken=result.get('nextPageToken')
df=pd.DataFrame(files)
print(df)
```

If anybody knows how to build a kind of google API crawler to detect all existing files that would help me a ton. Thank you for your attention <3

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I edited the way I used to list the files. Is that what you meant?